# How to display the value of javascript variable inside option tag in select statement using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have got the values of two JavaScript variables. I wanted to give inside the option tag in the value attribute. How to give that in jQuery as I wanted to retrieve the value of that option in the select statement?

Now I have currently given it. but it is displaying the variable not the value.

```
var packagetype = item.package_type;
var package_price = item.package_price;


$("select.selectedpackagetype").append("<option class='firstoption' value='packagetype:package_price'> "+packagetype+" - Rs. "+package_price+"</option>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now i have current given it. but it is displaying the variable not the value.

Well, of course it is. You've put the text `packagetype:package_price` literally inside the string. Elsewhere in that same line you use string concatenation, which is also what you might use for `value`:

```
$("select.selectedpackagetype").append("<option class='firstoption' value='" + packagetype + ":" + package_price + "'> "+packagetype+" - Rs. "+package_price+"</option>");
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But I wouldn't use string concatenation to build HTML for the option; I'd build the option *object* and then append it:

```
var packagetype = item.package_type;
var package_price = item.package_price;

$("<option>")
    .val(packagetype + ":" + package_price)
    .addClass("firstoption")
    .text(packagetype + " - Rs. " + package_price)
    .appendTo("select.selectedpackagetype");
```

Example:

```js
var packagetype = "TheType";
var package_price = 42;
    
$("<option>")
    .val(packagetype + ":" + package_price)
    .addClass("firstoption")
    .text(packagetype + " - Rs. " + package_price)
    .appendTo("select.selectedpackagetype");
```

```html
<select class="selectedpackagetype"></select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This syntax can also be used, right?  `$("<option>",{ "value":packagetype + ":" + package_price,"class":"firstoption","text":packagetype + " - Rs. " + package_price})
    .appendTo("select.selectedpackagetype");`

Comment: @mplungjan: It can, yes; that's [this form](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes). I don't like it, not least because of the potential for confusion, such as the issue with `size` that the docs call out.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.

```
  $("select.selectedpackagetype").append("<option class='firstoption' value='" + packagetype + ":" + package_price+ "'> "+packagetype+" - Rs. "+package_price+"</option>");
```

But T.J Crowders technique is better if you had the time to change your approach.